# Is there any way to stop object method execution from another method?

Tags: php, oop, halt

Situation is as follows:

There is a separate object that is responsible for generating page content, we can call it **Content**. Another object is its' parent - **Core** object.
**Content** object calls **Core** method *Check_parameters_count($parameters_count)*, so **Core** has to check if given parameters count in the URI equals to the integer given while executing this method ($parameters_count), if not - **Core** should generate error page and stop executing **Content's** rendering method.

Is there any way I can do this without using **if** statement? Just using *$core->Check_parameters_count(2)* in the **content** class in order to simplify job of the specific rendering engine programmers.

Everything should look similar to this:

```
 class Core {
    public function Check_parameters_count($parameters_count) {
        if (count($this->parameters) != $parameters_count) {
            $this->Show_error(404);
            $this->Stop_executing($content, 'Render');
            //or
            stop($content->Render);
            //or something similar..
        }
    }
}

class Content {
    public function Render() {
        //check given parameters so we could know which page should be rendered and how many parameters should be given
        //...
        //lets say we should have exactly 2 parameters
        $parameters_count = 2;
        //check it
        $core->Check_parameters_count($parameters_count);
        //if parameters count matched - continue method execution
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

You have 3 scopes:

- Function A (caller of function B)
- Function B
- Caller of function A

If you throw an exception in Function B, and make a try/catch block in caller of function A, function A execution will be interrupted by the exception. In fact - all code execution will be interrupted, up to a level which is enclosed in a corresponding try/catch block.

Comment: Good idea :) that's exactly what I was looking for.
This is the first time exceptions is useful for me, cause I always ceased using them because of the lack of the multi-error throwing at the same time.